# Validation in elementor form

Tags: validation, elementor

in elementor form I want validate the phone field to ONLY accept 9-10 numbers, in less than 9 number it's work good but in 11 numbers and up it send the form what should I have to add to limit until 10 numbers, thankshere is my code:

// Elementor Form Telephone Number Validition
//======================================
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/validation/tel', function( $field, $record, $ajax_handler ) {
// Match this format XXXXXXXXXX, 1234567890
if ( preg_match( '/[0-9]{10}/', $field['value'] ) !== 1 ) {
$ajax_handler->add_error( $field['id'], 'הזן טלפון חוקי בעל 9-10 ספרות ללא מקף או רווח' );
}
    }, 10, 3 );

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

/[0-9]{10}/ matches if it contains 10 digits at any position, so "abc-0123456789.xzy" would be fine.
/^[0-9]{10}$/ matches if it is exactly 10 digits, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: The answer is right on why he is having that issue, but he specifies in the question that 9 or 10 numbers are allowed so I would suggest to update the answer to `^\d{9,10}$`; note that as they are only numbers you can use the digit character to simplify.